# Boot problem after NVMe SSD cloning Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd, clone

I booted an ubuntu 18.04 live system and copied both partitions of my old Ubuntu 18.04 NVMe-SSD (one EFI System Partition fat32 and one ext4 partition, no encryption) onto a new one of the same size (it's just faster) in GParted and reformated the old NVMe-SSD and gave it a new UUID, also.

If I just install the new SSD, there are no problems. But if I also install the empty old SSD into a second M.2 slot, the system boots into emergency mode. Can anyone tell me why, and how to use both SSDs without boot problems?

I already used the standard procedure of the Boot-Repair tool and "update-grub", but the problem remains. What am I missing?

Thank you!
Cheers

Comment: Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. Did you also change GUIDs? This is where I find a new install & copy /home, list of apps to reinstall & perhaps some settings in /etc to new install from your backup. Confirms backup has everything you need when drive fails and you have no recourse. And you still have old drive to update backup if missing something.

Comment: @oldfred: Thanks! I didn't post a Report when I used Boot-Repair. The GUID of the old SSD was changed, not the new one. The data of my system is also backed up additionally, so there is no loss involved, but the new installation of all programms would cost me 3 days, so I preferred a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue in terms of using both NVMe SSDs by changing a faulty SATA cable of a third SSD. Although I would still like to know how that could affect a system in such an unusual way, it's now working as intended at least.
Thanks and Cheers!

Comment: Nice to see the problem is resolved for you. Faulty hardware can cause all sort of errors that may not be obvious. Data received from the drive could be overflowing some register, but that's only assuming.

Answer (score 1):

There will be lot of assuming, because question lacks data, such as full steps to reproduce the issue.

Copying partitions and whole disk are not the same thing.

You can check the ESD partition flag and make sure they are appropriate using gparted. (ESD + boot)

You would also need to verify your grub efi file is in your esd partition with a valid configuration file.
Valid configuration file may use partitions UUID, since you modified them you must verify the value are correct.

Suggestion for future migration would be to use dd from raw device to raw device or use clonezilla disk to disk clone, as your need was to migrate the whole storage including partition table and not specific data partition.

Comment: Thanks! ESP and BOOT flags are set on EFi partition, the grub file is valid and the UUID correct. I will prefer Clonezilla in the future.